# Is it a little bit unnatural to use visit when talking about parents?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I live with my wife and son. My parents live 3 blocks away and *visit* us monthly.

Is it a little bit unnatural to use **visit** here? They are my parents, not other relatives like aunt, niece and nephews.

Comment: If you are living in their house, while they spend most of their time traveling, then *visit* would be strange; they'd be coming home.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Does "their house" mean ownership?

Comment: Ownership *and* regular residence.  My scenario is somewhat farfetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems perfectly normal to me (British English).

Comment: Thank you! If I say "they come to see us monthly", does it mean the same?

Comment: Yes. That's another way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

Since "**visit**" has many definitions related to "*coming in order to spend time*" then we can say that there is absolutely no difference in who is visiting whom.

- Will your mom visit us (pay us a visit) on Sunday?
- I went to London to visit my friend Jack.
- My sister visited me when she was on vacation.
- Will you visit your grandma in hospital tomorrow?

Almost in all cases **"to visit"** means *"to come and spend time with as a relative or guest"*, but it can also mean *"to attend a place for admiration and (or) sightseeing"* which is:

- I visited New York last year and took some photos.
- We are planning to visit the art museum in the evening.